# Complex number sequence question

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, proof-writing

So if I have $$z_{0}=4\sqrt2 \, \left( \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right) + i \sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right) \right)$$ and $$z_{1}=2 \left( \cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right) + i \sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right) \right)$$

$$z_{n}=2\sqrt{2} \, \left(\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{4}\right) + i \sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{4} \right) \right)\, \frac{z_{n-1}}{|z_{n-2}|}$$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, with $n \geq2$. So the $z_{n}$ is sequence. Can I find two things,

1. Determine smallest positive integer $p$ such that for every positive integer $n$, |$z_{n+p}$|=|$z_{n}$|
2. Determine smallest positive integer $q$ such that for every positive integer $n$, $z_{n+q}$=$z_{n}$

These 2 is very similar, first one is looking for abslute value of it, and second one is not. I think at end of the sequence, there is $\frac{z_{n-1}}{|z_{n-2}|}$. This is maybe related. Anyway of using this to prove it? I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write each of the numbers in polar form; $z_n=r_ne^{i\theta_n}$. See if you can use the given recurrences to set up recurrences for $r_n$ and $\theta_n$, which should be easier to deal with.

Comment: I wrote it in polar form. How can I continue next?

Comment: Have you been able to write recurrences for $r_n$ and $\theta_n$ separately? If so, do you know how to figure out the minimal period of each?

Comment: No. I am not expert at this. Is there another way to solve it?